# Error para salir de un Thread

Tags: python, hilos, selenium-webdriver, telegram-bot

Tengo un programa en py-telegram-bot en donde ingresan varios usuarios y le piden informacion al programa. El programa busca lo que necesitan en internet mediante selenium y se lo manda.
Mi problema es que varios usuarios pueden ingresar comandos o pedir informacion a la vez por lo que ncesito que les responda a todos a la vez y no por turnos.
Con thread estaria funcionando perfecto esa parte, pero tengo un problema para salir de ahi

```
def confirmaelticket(update, context):
    if context.user_data['result'] == "ESPERAORDENES":
        return esperaordenes(update, context)
    if context.user_data['result'] == "ESPERAERROR":
        return esperaerror(update, context)
    if context.user_data['result'] == "INDICATICKET":
        return indicaticket(update, context)
    if context.user_data['result'] == "INDICANODOCMTS":
        return indicanodocmts(update, context)
    if context.user_data['result'] is None:
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(update, context))
        t.start()
        
def worker (update, context):
    respuesta = update.message.text.lower()
    if respuesta == "si":
        try:
            mensaje_a_supervisores = f'El técnico {context.user_data["Tecnico"]} inició con el ticket: {context.user_data["Ticket"]}.'
            enviar_mensaje_a_supervisores(context, mensaje_a_supervisores)
            context.user_data["TicketEnCurso"] = True
            update.message.reply_text(f"Perfecto. Estoy buscando la información de su ticket. Espere unos segundos.")
            #Ingresa a la pagina
            try:
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=OpcionesChrome)
                #Realiza las busquedas a la perfeccion
            recibecomandos = True
            context.user_data['RecibeComandos'] = recibecomandos
            print ("Esperaordenes")
            result = "ESPERAORDENES"
            context.user_data['result'] = result
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Se produjo una excepción: {e}")
            update.message.reply_text("Se produjo un error inesperado. Contacte con soporte.")
            result = "ESPERAERROR"
            context.user_data['result'] = result
    elif respuesta == "no":
        update.message.reply_text("Inserte el número de ticket.")
        context
        result = "INDICATICKET"
        context.user_data['result'] = result
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Por favor, ingrese Si o No.")
```

Necesitaria algo para cerrar el thread una vez que tiene el resultado para el usuario, pero no se como.
Estuve viendo que tambien se puede hacer con multiprocessing, pero desconozco el tema. Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida

Comment: Los hilos terminan por sí solos en el momento en que llegan al final de la función. Por lo tanto, si deseas que un hilo no muera debes usar un `while True`. ¿Seguro que necesitas *cerrarlo*? ***Once the thread's activity is started, the thread is considered 'alive'. It stops being alive when its run() method terminates.*** [Extracto de la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

Comment: Necesito que salga de ese hilo una vez que tenga el "resultado" para seguir con el programa. El problema es que de la forma que lo estoy haciendo siempre vuelve a confirmaelticket. Si un usuario manda un mensaje y el resultado habia sido ESPERAERROR vuelve a mandar siempre lo que hay en def esperaerror aunque al final de eso tenga un return a otra funcion. No se si me explico.